# How to structure a Ruby on Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, database-design, model

In our app's User model, we already have:

```
attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

Now, we need to add relationship associations to the model, namely:

```
has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
has_many :agendas, through: :roles
```

Does it matter whether we include the latter go BEFORE or AFTER the former, in the model?

If so, what is the recommended / preferred / best way?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. The preferred way is the most readable. Typically associations in one section, validations in another, callbacks in another. And be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter, but the important thing is to be consistent. A usual best practice is to first do all you can to declare the class' structure, before you get in to any operational details. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token

  has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :agendas, through: :roles

  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
end
```

Again, this is just one way to do things, but it's very common amongst Rails applications.